# LRU cache on disk for python

Tags: python, caching, lru

Am looking for on disk LRU cache package in Python.
Most of them are in memory cache.

Main reason is Database access is slow and
have limited RAM for in memory LRU.
However, large and fast SSD for LRU cache.

Comment: cache model depends on data structures to access : what data type and indexeds do you plan to use ?

Comment: Dictionnary type key is string and value is string or binary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One solution is DISKCACHE :
http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/tutorial.html

The core of DiskCache is diskcache.Cache which represents a disk and file backed cache. As a Cache it supports a familiar Python Mapping interface with additional cache and performance parameter

Answer (score 8):

You can also just go with `shelve`, which is part of the Python Standard SDK. https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html

Comment: That's a dictionary, not an LRU cache.

Comment: Not LRU but works for me! thanks for pointing this out